# Videos from '/static' not rendering in a flask application

Tags: python, html, flask, video-streaming, html5-video

I am currently facing an issue in my project where the user can successfully upload videos to a '/static' directory. When the user tried to view the videos at '/upload-panel' the videos don't render. The video data is being sent successfully as the video titles appear. The goal is to have a panel of videos appear that the user can then go and watch. The relevant code is as follows

Python

```
@routes_bp.route('/upload-panel')
def upload_panel():
    upload_directory = 'static'

    uploaded_videos = []

    for root, _, files in os.walk(upload_directory):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(('.mp4', '.avi', '.mkv')):
                video_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                relative_path = os.path.relpath(video_path, upload_directory)
                uploaded_videos.append(relative_path)
                print(uploaded_videos)

    return render_template('upload_panel.html', uploaded_videos=uploaded_videos)
```

HTML

```
    <h1 class="text-center">View your videos here</h1>

    <div class="row">
        {% for video in uploaded_videos %}
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
            <div class="card">
                <video controls width="100%">
                    <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename=video) }}" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ video.split('/')[-1] }}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

The full project and code can be viewed at https://github.com/User1420552/auslanTranslator

I already tried created a new application where the only function is to send the file and I couldn't figure out any way to send the file. Even after numerous attempts at using ChatGPT to help, I couldn't come to a solution.